# How to call a list of objects from a session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an invoice like this:
For signed in users, I save the invoices and the invoice units to database (one invoice has many invoice units) and for users that are not signed in, I am trying to save the data into sessions

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Invoice invoice)
    {
        var userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "UserId")?.Value;
        if (userId is not null)
        {
            invoice.UserId = Guid.Parse(userId.ToString());
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            invoice.DateCreated = dateTime;
            foreach (var invoiceUnit in invoice.InvoiceUnits)
            {
                db.InvoiceUnits.Add(invoiceUnit);
            }
            db.Add(invoice);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            invoice.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            var invoicesFromSession = GetInvoicesFromSession();
            var invoiceUnitsFromSession = GetInvoiceUnitsFromSession();

            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            invoice.DateCreated = dateTime;

            if (invoice is not null)
            {
                invoicesFromSession.Add(invoice);

                HttpContext.Session.SetString("invoice", JsonSerializer.Serialize(invoicesFromSession));

                foreach(var invoiceUnit in invoice.InvoiceUnits)
                {
                    invoiceUnit.Id = new Guid();
                    invoiceUnit.InvoiceId = invoice.Id;
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("invoiceUnit", JsonSerializer.Serialize(invoiceUnitsFromSession));
                    invoiceUnitsFromSession.Add(invoiceUnit);
                }

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
```

I am getting the invoice units from session like this:

```
    private List<InvoiceUnit> GetInvoiceUnitsFromSession()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.LoadAsync();
        var sessionString = HttpContext.Session.GetString("invoiceUnit");
        if (sessionString is not null)
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<InvoiceUnit>>(sessionString);
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<InvoiceUnit>().ToList();
    }
```

And then I am trying to call the function in the Edit controller

```
            var sessionInvoices = GetInvoicesFromSession();
            var sessionInvoiceUnits = GetInvoiceUnitsFromSession();
            var invoiceFromDbSession = sessionInvoices.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
            List<InvoiceUnit> invoiceUnitsForInvoiceSession = new List<InvoiceUnit>();

            foreach (var invoiceUnit in sessionInvoiceUnits)
            {
                if (invoiceUnit.InvoiceId == id)
                {
                    invoiceUnitsForInvoiceSession.Add(invoiceUnit);
                }
            }
            GenericModel sessionData = new GenericModel(invoiceUnitsForInvoiceSession, invoiceFromDbSession);
            return View(sessionData);
```

From some reason tho, when I call the `GetInvoiceUnitsFromSession();` in the Edit controller to retrieve the wanted invoice unit for the specific invoice, I only receive one invoice unit for each invoice (the first one I have entered). When I debug the `invoiceUnitsFromSession` variable in the create function, the number of units fits just fine for the specific invoice so I think there must be some problem in the way I am trying to retreive the session. Any idea what changes to make in order to retreive all of the invoice units I recieve for all invoices so I can get them in Edit controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you see comes from this block:

```
                foreach(var invoiceUnit in invoice.InvoiceUnits)
                {
                    invoiceUnit.Id = new Guid();
                    invoiceUnit.InvoiceId = invoice.Id;
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("invoiceUnit", JsonSerializer.Serialize(invoiceUnitsFromSession)); // Specifically this line
                    invoiceUnitsFromSession.Add(invoiceUnit);
                }
```

Here you're writing the value for the key `invoiceUnit` on each repetition of the loop before you actually update the value, so at least the last line will always be missing. You would want to either change the order:

```
                foreach(var invoiceUnit in invoice.InvoiceUnits)
                {
                    invoiceUnit.Id = new Guid();
                    invoiceUnit.InvoiceId = invoice.Id;
                    invoiceUnitsFromSession.Add(invoiceUnit);
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString(
                       "invoiceUnit", 
                       JsonSerializer.Serialize(invoiceUnitsFromSession));
                }
```

or move the line that stores invoice units into the session out of the loop completely to avoid unnecessary repetition:

```
                foreach(var invoiceUnit in invoice.InvoiceUnits)
                {
                    invoiceUnit.Id = new Guid();
                    invoiceUnit.InvoiceId = invoice.Id;
                    invoiceUnitsFromSession.Add(invoiceUnit);
                }
                HttpContext.Session.SetString(
                   "invoiceUnit", 
                   JsonSerializer.Serialize(invoiceUnitsFromSession));
```

Answer (score 1):

> call a list of objects from a session

Do you want the below way?

Configure your SessionExtension like below:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
    }

    public static T? Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Then use methods like below:

```
////  your list object
List<MyClass> classCollection = new List<MyClass>();

//// To set value in session
HttpContext.Session.Set<List<MyClass>>("someKey", classCollection);

//// To Get Value from Session
List<MyClass> classCollection = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<MyClass>>("someKey");
```

Read [Set and get Session values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-and-get-session-values) to know more.